# How can search for something and then change some text in table column by MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some records in MYSQL database with domain name, Now i changed domain and i want use query for find these word `example.com` in record column and then change to `example.net`.

I think if column only include domain, it's very easy but my records include domain name and some text. Like this:

> it's a sample text www.sample.com and i want change it

I have some recorde like above and i want find every recorde that have `sample.com` text and then change it to `sample.net`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = REPLACE(mycolumn,'www.sample.com','www.sample.net');
```

[Replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) for this:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column> = REPLACE(<column>, 'www.sample.com', 'www.example.net');
```

The above will replace all occurances of `www.sample.com` with `www.example.net` in the specified column.